# Knowledge graph visualization

Tags: data-visualization

I have created an RDF knowledge graph in turtle and would like to visualize its concepts using infoboxes similar to Wikipedia/Google. I would also like to show the relationships between concepts. Any free software that you can recommend? My knowledge graph has a historical background with entities such as Dates, People, Places and Keywords

Comment: I'm looking for something similar.  I'd like to take an RDF/Turtle file and generate it's RDFS Schema and/or OWL ontology.  Did you ever find a tool?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot what you search for? - Meanwhile, there is [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/). Not RDF, but plain Markdown, which could be well-suited in other settings.